# Add Java Annotations programmatically

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I have a model which has a @Column(nullable=false) annotation for Hibernate and for all fields that have nullable = false, I would like to programmatically add a few new annotations like @NotNull and @ApiModelProperty(required = true) - used for swagger.

So, I would like to be able to parse all fields from the models from my application, get the existing annotations and based on those to add new ones. Can this be done?

UPDATE: The thing is that everytime a new field is added, if it's not nullable, then at least 2 other annotations need to be added for certain frameworks and it's easy to forget all that are required. Also, I would also like to add some annotations based on the @Column length property -> like @Length that would generate a validation error and it's a bit tedious to go through all the code and double-check that we've added all the missing annotations. That's why I was wondering if I could have something of a config class where I could parse all entities and add the missing annotations.

Comment: Why programatically? Assume you have a script in mind. Anything is possible. But this i do not recommend. You just need a good IDE to replace the line @Column(nullable=false) with multiple lines i.e. same column + the extras you need. Intellij IDEA is just right for me with multiline replace, afterwards you can reformat code all you want.

Comment: Updated question. (I tried to comment first, but I couldn't; not sure why i could now)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [Programmatic constraint definition](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.3/reference/en-US/html/validator-specifics.html#programmaticapi). Below is an example using FluentApi format. Extend it to fit your needs

```
ConstraintMapping mapping = new ConstraintMapping();
mapping.type( Car.class )
    .property( "manufacturer", FIELD )
        .constraint( new NotNullDef() )
    .property( "licensePlate", FIELD )
        .constraint( new NotNullDef() )
        .constraint( new SizeDef().min( 2 ).max( 14 ) )
    .property( "seatCount", FIELD )
        .constraint( new MinDef()value ( 2 ) )
.type( RentalCar.class )
    .property( "rentalStation", METHOD )
        .constraint( new NotNullDef() );
```

Further details and examples are available [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.3/reference/en-US/html/validator-specifics.html#programmaticapi)

Additional [resource here](http://portofino.manydesigns.com/en/blog/configuring-hibernate-programmatically?) (a bit old, but still holds good)